# SQL не возвращает данные

Tags: android, sql, база-данных

Из сайта я подгружаю список диалогов, потом добавляю их в БД. 
Дело в том что диалоги добавляются (возвращается позиция), но не выводятся. getCount() = 0 всегда.
Пробовал убирать sql.execSQL("DELETE FROM dialogs"); , все ровно не выводит. В чем может быть проблема?

```
public static final void putItems(JSONArray items) {
    SQLiteDatabase sql = ApplicationName.getDb();
    sql.execSQL("DELETE FROM dialogs");
    sql.beginTransaction();
    for (int i = 0; i < items.length(); i++) {
        try {
            ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
            contentValues.put("json", items.getJSONObject(i).toString());
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, String.valueOf(sql.insert("dialogs", null, contentValues)));
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, String.valueOf(e));
        }
    }
    sql.endTransaction();
}

public static final JSONArray getDialogs() {
    SQLiteDatabase sql = ApplicationName.getDb();
    JSONArray items = new JSONArray();
    Cursor c = sql.query("dialogs", null, null, null, null, null, "position DESC LIMIT 24");
    if (c != null && c.moveToFirst()) {
        int jsonColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("json");
        do {
            try {
                items.put(new JSONObject(c.getString(jsonColIndex)));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, String.valueOf(e));
            }
        } while (c.moveToNext());
    }
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "size: " + c.getCount() + ", items: " + items);
    c.close();
    return items;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не помечаете что транзакция завершилась успешно. Должно быть так

```
    database.beginTransaction();
    try {

        //сохранение данных в бд

        database.setTransactionSuccessful();
   } finally {
        database.endTransaction();
   }
```